# Blank Service worker script

Tags: javascript, service-worker

The service worker script is blank

I am trying to implement `service workers` into my web app however i noticed nothing was working. I get confirmation that the service worker starts however when i try to view it in the chrome tools it shows a blank document. All efforts to console log etc are unsuccessful which is leading me to believe that the file is truly blank despite it obviously not being.

I have tried unregistered the service worker and updating manually.

**SCRIPT ON INDEX**

```js
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw_basic.js')
      .then(function(reg) {
        // registration worked
        console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // registration failed
        console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
      });
    }
```

**SERVICE WORKER SCRIPT**

```js
    var CACHE_NAME = 'my-site-cache-v1';
    var urlsToCache = [
      './', './index.php',
      './profile.php',
      './support.php',
      './img/dance3-min.png',
      './css/agency',
      './css/agency.min.css',
      './css/eventform.css',
      './css/loginmodal.css',
      './css/profile.css',
      './css/support.css',
      './css/table.css',
      './css/timer.css'
    ]



    self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
      event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
        .then(function(cache) {
          console.log('Opened Cache');
          return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
        })
      );
    });



    self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event)) {
      event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
            console.log('Successfully fetched resource from chache: ${event.request.url}');
            return response;
          } else {
            console.error('Failed to fetch resource: ${event.request.url}');
          }
          return fetch(event.request);
          }
        )

      )

    }
```

EDIT* I have gotten it to update by changing the name of the js file and manually unregistering the service worker in chrome however it doesn't always update this way sometimes requiring several attempts

I still feel like there must be a better way for doing this and in all the tutorials / documentation it seems like it  should install the new one and activate once all tabs are unloaded but its not even installing the updated one at all.

EDIT* 
I noticed the service worker tries to install and then disappears.
Example- Service worker #12 is active and running. I refresh and then for a second service worker #24 is installing and then suddenly its gone. At this point i really don't know whats going on other feeds are saying its a problem with the cache max age but I have it set to 0 in the htaccess

```
Cache-Control: max-age= 0
```

EDIT* 
I have tried taking the service worker onto a different page remove the caching and just try to get it to update.

Currently my index looks like

```
<html>
  <head>

  <script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/beta/sw.js', {scope: '/beta/'})
  .then(function(reg) {
    // registration worked
    console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // registration failed
    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
  });
}
    </script>
</head>
online page v2.0
</html>
```

and the service worker looks like

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  console.log("SW installed");
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log("SW activated");
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log("Hijacked Signal");
  event.respondWith(new Response("offline page"));
});
```

This Works when the user refreshes after visiting the page the text changes from online to offline. The problem occurs when i change the desired text (eg to offline 2.0). Anyone who has already visited the website is running the old service worker and so will see offline  and not offline 2.0

a link to the page if anyone wishes to see whats going on

https://pakcollegelive.tk/beta/index.php

Comment: It is possible that cache.addAll is rejecting, and causing the install to fail. You may want to make sure your file paths are correct. I would advise checking out what happens with a console.log statement on the cache.addAll call.

Comment: Personally, I let the install continue even if some files fail, but that may not meet your criteria.

Comment: Can you provide us a link to your web app so that we can see what else is going on? I do not think we have enough information to solve this problem.

Comment: I do not believe that the cache max age is an issue. I have a web app on GitHub (which sends 10 minute cache control headers), and have never noticed an issue with it when it comes to the serviceworker.

Comment: I have tried removing caching from the script to see if that was the problem however my issue persists. I've added a link to the post hopefully that helps.

Comment: Ok. I think I have it.

Comment: Hmm... It looked like you might be hijacking the request for your serviceworker script. You can console.log the url being fetched to see if this is what is going on.

Comment: However according to https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/893, the serviceworker shouldn't be able to block a service worker fetch.

Comment: Please remember that in order for a serviceworker to update, the new serviceworker must have been downloaded, THEN all tabs from that origin must be closed (unless self.skipWaiting() and maybe clients.claim() is used), THEN the page must be opened again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out Cloudflare wasn't playing nice with the service worker files for whatever reason. It wasn't imperative that Cloudflare was used in my case so disabling it fixed the problem.